# What should be the relation between flange length and web thickness for an optimum I - beam?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science

I had this interesting thought while learning abut I-beams. Just curious to know if there is any relation or if the flange length and web thickness of I-beams is arbitary .
(edit: I am sorry, I should have specified that the beam must be optimised for bending stiffness.)

Comment: You also should have specified, what constraints the beam is subject to. As it stands, the optimal beam would be infintely wide in both cross-sectional directions. You see that it is not as easy as you think. While you introduce more and more constraints (like maximum mass, maximum space demand), you end up using computational methods in order to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I-beams are available in a variety of shape factors; there is no "optimum" shape. The central web supports the shear load and the flanges take up the bending moments; you select the right one based on what the shear load and maximum bending moment will be.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization requires the definition of a goal function (what to optimize for). Since there are a multitude of possible response properties of any mechanical system (for the beam, for example, two bending stiffnesses, torsional stiffness, different variants of buckling stability, strength, etc...) which almost always stay in conflict with each other (what improves one, deteriorates the other), it is not possible to optimize it in a general way.

You are responsible for specifying an appropriate goal function, i.e. what is most important for your application. For example, in building construction, the buckling stability of vertical beams is of foremost importance, while for the horizontal beams bending strength is primary.